# Writing and Editing Files (Python)

Tags: python, file-handling

First of all i would like to apologize since i am a beginner to Python. Anyway I have a Python Program where I can create text files with the general form:

```
Recipe Name:
Item
Weight
Number of people recipe serves
```

And what I'm trying to do is to allow the program to be able to retrieve the recipe and have the ingredients recalculated for a different number of people.  The program should output the the recipe name, the new number of people and the revised quantities for the new number of people. I am able to retrieve the recipe and output the recipe however i am not sure how to have the ingredients recaculated for a different number of people. This is part of my code:

```
def modify_recipe():
    Choice_Exist = input("\nOkaym it looks like you want to modify a recipe. Please enter the name of this recipe ")
    Exist_Recipe = open(Choice_Exist, "r+")
    time.sleep(2)
    ServRequire = int(input("Please enter how many servings you would like "))
```

Comment: What's your problem? You did not state anything about it. Did you take a look at [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) section of the python tutorial?

Comment: I cant figure out how to allow a user to multiply the original servings by entering how many servings are required, as the default servings are in a text file. Does anyone know how this can be done? I am new to file-handling and have been researching constantly but to no avail.

Comment: You could read your file into a dictionary or list, modify it and overwrite your existing file

Comment: Read the file, parse the contents, convert the numbers `int`/`float` (as you did in the last line of your code), multiply the numbers using `*`, convert them back to string and rewrite the file.  There's **plenty** of questions about any of these steps on SO.

Comment: Parse the contents? Could you provide an example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to edit it a couple times because I use Python 2.7.5, but this should work:

```
import time

def modify_recipe():
    Choice_Exist = input("\nOkay it looks like you want to modify a recipe. Please enter the name of this recipe: ")
    with open(Choice_Exist + ".txt", "r+") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        data_list = [word.replace("\n","") for word in content]

    time.sleep(2)

    ServRequire = int(input("Please enter how many servings you would like: "))

    print data_list[0]
    print data_list[1]
    print int(data_list[2])*ServRequire #provided the Weight is in line 3 of txt file
    print ServRequire

modify_recipe()
```

Comment: Thanks! It works but what does the this part of the code do?                                                          with open(Choice_Exist + ".txt", "r+") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        data_list = [word.replace("\n","") for word in content]

Comment: it opens the recipe textfile inputted in the line before and reads each line into the list `content`. And in this list there are "newlines" (`\n`) after each entry in the list. So `data_list` removes all these unwanted `\n` characters.

Comment: @Maxine123 If my code works could you accept my answer? :) (Press the green checkmark) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend splitting your effort into multiple steps, and working on each step (doing research, trying to write the code, asking specific questions) in succession.

1) Look up [python's file I/O](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). 1.a) Try to recreate the examples you find to make sure you understand what each piece of the code does. 1.b) Write your own script that accomplishes *just this piece* of your desired program, i.e. opens an exist recipe text file or creates a new one.

2) Really use you're own functions in Python particularly with passing your own arguments. What you're trying to make is a perfect example of good "[modular programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming)", were you would right a function that reads an input file, another that writes an output file, another that prompts users for they number they'd like to multiple, and so on.

3) Add a `try/except` block for user input. If a user enters a non-numeric value, this will allow you to catch that and prompt the user again for a corrected value. Something like:

```
while True:
  servings = raw_input('Please enter the number of servings desired: ')
  try:
    svgs = int(servings)
    break
  except ValueError:
    print('Please check to make sure you entered a numeric value, with no'
        +' letters or words, and a whole integer (no decimals or fractions).')
```

Or if you want to allow decimals, you could use `float()` instead of `int()`.

4) [Semi-Advanced] Basic regular expressions (aka "regex") will be *very* helpful in building out what you're making. It sounds like your input files will have a strict, predictable format, so regex probably isn't necessary. But if you're looking to accept non-standard recipe input files, regex would be a great tool. While it can be a bit hard or confusing skill to learn, but there are a lot of good tutorials and guides. A few I bookmarked in the past are [Python Course](http://www.python-course.eu/re.php), [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions), and [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/regular_expressions/). And a fantastic tool I strongly recommend while learning to build your own regular expression patterns is [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/) (or one of many similar, like [PythonRegex](http://www.pythonregex.com/)), which show you what parts of your pattern are working or not working and why.

Here's an outline to help get you started:

```
def read_recipe_default(filename):
  # open the file that contains the default ingredients

def parse_recipe(recipe):
  # Use your regex to search for amounts here. Some useful basics include 
  # '\d' for numbers, and looking for keywords like 'cups', 'tbsp', etc.

def get_multiplier():
  # prompt user for their multiplier here

def main():
  # Call these methods as needed here. This will be the first part 
  #  of your program that runs.
  filename = ...
  file_contents = read_recipe_file(filename)
  # ...

# This last piece is what tells Python to start with the main() function above.
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Starting out can be tough, but it's very worth it in the end! Good luck!